# How to make span wrap words without defining a width or max-width on the container div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following partially generated generated and simplified code which is used to display warnings or errors in Dojo dialogs:

```css
/*Relevant CSS:*/

.l-status-message-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  min-height: 15px;
}

.l-status-message-wrapper--dialog {
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.c-global-message {
  min-height: 15px;
  color: #a5cf42;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.c-global-message--error {
  color: #e31d25;
}

.dijitDialog {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #adadad;
  padding: 0;
}

.dijitDialog {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  background: #C9CFD2 url(../../images/onglet_bg.gif) repeat-x;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  background: #fafafa url(images/titleBar.png) repeat-x top left;
  padding: 5px 6px 3px 6px;
  outline: 0;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  cursor: move;
}

form {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dijitDialog dijitDialogFocused dijitFocused" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="machineParameterDialog_title" id="machineParameterDialog" widgetid="machineParameterDialog">
  <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleBar" class="dijitDialogTitleBar">
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitDialogTitle" id="machineParameterDialog_title" role="heading" level="1">Edit Machine Parameter</span>
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeButtonNode" class="dijitDialogCloseIcon" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: onCancel" title="Cancel" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeText" class="closeText" title="Cancel">x</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="dijitDialogPaneContent" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
    <div id="machineParameterDialogContents" class="machineParameterDialogContents">
      <span class="l-status-message-wrapper l-status-message-wrapper--dialog">
        <span id="machineParameterDialogStatus" class="c-global-message c-global-message--error">
          error: <span>Action not successful. Please correct the validation errors</span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <form id="machineParameterDialogForm" name="machineParameterDialogForm" action="/machineParameterAction.action" method="POST" class="c-panel-dialog">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like long text in `.l-status-message-wrapper--dialog` to not increase the width of the .machineParameterDialogContents div.

However, I'd rather not give the .machineParameterDialogContents div or any of the parent divs a `width` or `max-width`. I want the container to adjust the width based on the widest element AFTER the component with long text, which can vary on a page by page basis and sometimes even be different on the same page for the same dialog depending on what action is being performed. To clarify: It's the outside .machineParameterDialogContents div I don't want to widen, not the `.l-status-message-wrapper--dialog` span. That span should widen to at most the size of any other components in the page. Also, everything inside the machineParameterDialogContents div is loaded through Ajax, in case it's relevant.

So in the above example, I don't want the span to be more than 200px, and the rest should automatically wrap, but I want this without defining a max-width on the span or the machineParameterDialogContents div. Note that I have given the form a fixed width, but in reality this width can change between dialog loads and is pretty dynamic.

Is this at all possible? I need to support Chrome, Firefox and IE11.

Comment: What controls the width of `.container` currently? or what styles do you have for it? is it under another wrapper which has a width?

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing, a div is display block by default and takes on 100% width of its container. Your span inside of the div is also block as you defined it. So it wouldn't increase the width of the container no matter how much text is in it(with the given code).

Comment: @Huangism I'll update the question with a fuller example. My main issue is that a lot of the code is generated and CSS spread over a couple dozen files.

Comment: use inspector to grab the css you need, basically you need to demonstrate the issue for us to come up with a solution. Currently, I can't tell what the issue you are having is

Comment: @Huangism I think I have something that mostly matches what I have right now and what explains what I wish to do. It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: @Huangism Okay, I think it should be clearer now. There's a bit of CSS still in there related to page formatting, but the core is there.

Comment: So basically, you want `#machineParameterDialogContents` width to be based on the forms width right?

Comment: @Huangism Yes and no. In this case, the form is the element I want to base the width on, but it's simply because it's the next biggest element after the statusmessage span. To put it differently, I'd like #machineparameterdialogcontents width to ignore the status span for determining the width, and then the status span to fill up that width.

Comment: Well the only way to do that is to take the error text out of the document flow but then you would have trouble lining it up unless you know how much space the error message would take. If you know how big the error message is you can make the error position absolute and set width to 100% (takes on parent width) and you can use margin or padding to make the space for the error message. Or you use js to get the biggest item and set width to your error or containing parent. Doesn't this dialog have a width somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigating, our webdesigner has found a solution involving putting a flexbox around the span. I'm sharing the solution below for anyone else with this problem.

```css
/*Relevant CSS:*/

.l-status-message-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  min-height: 15px;
}

.l-status-message-wrapper--dialog {
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.c-global-message {
  min-height: 15px;
  color: #a5cf42;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.c-global-message--error {
  color: #e31d25;
}

.dijitDialog {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #adadad;
  padding: 0;
}

.dijitDialog {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  background: #C9CFD2 url(../../images/onglet_bg.gif) repeat-x;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  background: #fafafa url(images/titleBar.png) repeat-x top left;
  padding: 5px 6px 3px 6px;
  outline: 0;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  cursor: move;
}

form {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

/* Limits the width of an element so it does not exceed the width of the largest element 
 * on the same DOM level. It will adjust the width of its contents in cases where the parent
 * element has no width value set. (e.g. A dialog message span that may not exceed the width of a accompagnied c-panel-dialog)
 * 
 * Always use in a hierarchical markup combination (l-dynamic-width-wrapper > l-dynamic-width-wrapper-items)
 */
.l-dynamic-width-wrapper {
 display: flex; 
}

.l-dynamic-width-wrapper > .l-dynamic-width-wrapper-items {
   flex-grow: 1;
   width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dijitDialog dijitDialogFocused dijitFocused" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="machineParameterDialog_title" id="machineParameterDialog" widgetid="machineParameterDialog">
  <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleBar" class="dijitDialogTitleBar">
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitDialogTitle" id="machineParameterDialog_title" role="heading" level="1">Edit Machine Parameter</span>
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeButtonNode" class="dijitDialogCloseIcon" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: onCancel" title="Cancel" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeText" class="closeText" title="Cancel">x</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="dijitDialogPaneContent" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
    <div id="machineParameterDialogContents" class="machineParameterDialogContents">
      <div class="l-dynamic-width-wrapper">
       <div class="l-dynamic-width-wrapper-items">
       <span class="l-status-message-wrapper l-status-message-wrapper--dialog">
        <span id="machineParameterDialogStatus" class="c-global-message c-global-message--error">
          error: <span>Action not successful. Please correct the validation errors</span>
        </span>
      </span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <form id="machineParameterDialogForm" name="machineParameterDialogForm" action="/machineParameterAction.action" method="POST" class="c-panel-dialog">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest add to what you already had is to just add

`max-width: fit-content` to `.l-status-message-wrapper--dialog`

and it makes the text fit the available width and doesn't add to the overall width

```css
/*Relevant CSS:*/

.l-status-message-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  min-height: 15px;
}

.l-status-message-wrapper--dialog {
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: block;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.c-global-message {
  min-height: 15px;
  color: #a5cf42;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.c-global-message--error {
  color: #e31d25;
}

.dijitDialog {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #adadad;
  padding: 0;
}

.dijitDialog {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  background: #C9CFD2 url(../../images/onglet_bg.gif) repeat-x;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  background: #fafafa url(images/titleBar.png) repeat-x top left;
  padding: 5px 6px 3px 6px;
  outline: 0;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  cursor: move;
}

form {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dijitDialog dijitDialogFocused dijitFocused" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="machineParameterDialog_title" id="machineParameterDialog" widgetid="machineParameterDialog">
  <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleBar" class="dijitDialogTitleBar">
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitDialogTitle" id="machineParameterDialog_title" role="heading" level="1">Edit Machine Parameter</span>
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeButtonNode" class="dijitDialogCloseIcon" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: onCancel" title="Cancel" role="button" tabindex="0">
            <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeText" class="closeText" title="Cancel">x</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="dijitDialogPaneContent" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
    <div id="machineParameterDialogContents" class="machineParameterDialogContents">
      <span class="l-status-message-wrapper l-status-message-wrapper--dialog">
        <span id="machineParameterDialogStatus" class="c-global-message c-global-message--error">
          error: <span>Action not successful. Please correct the validation errors</span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <form id="machineParameterDialogForm" name="machineParameterDialogForm" action="/machineParameterAction.action" method="POST" class="c-panel-dialog">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` and add another div on the right. Then set flex-grow: 1 for both. If the right div have more content it will take the rest of the screen, if not, the left div will stretch. I think it's the best you can do without defining any width.

```css
/*Relevant CSS:*/

.l-status-message-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  min-height: 15px;
}

.l-status-message-wrapper--dialog {
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.c-global-message {
  min-height: 15px;
  color: #a5cf42;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.c-global-message--error {
  color: #e31d25;
}

.dijitDialog {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #adadad;
  padding: 0;
}

.dijitDialog {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  background: #C9CFD2 url(../../images/onglet_bg.gif) repeat-x;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  background: #fafafa url(images/titleBar.png) repeat-x top left;
  padding: 5px 6px 3px 6px;
  outline: 0;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
  cursor: move;
}

form {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.dijitDialogPaneContent{
  display: flex;
}

.machineParameterDialogContents{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.more-content{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dijitDialog dijitDialogFocused dijitFocused" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="machineParameterDialog_title" id="machineParameterDialog" widgetid="machineParameterDialog">
  <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleBar" class="dijitDialogTitleBar">
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitDialogTitle" id="machineParameterDialog_title" role="heading" level="1">Edit Machine Parameter</span>
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeButtonNode" class="dijitDialogCloseIcon" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: onCancel" title="Cancel" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeText" class="closeText" title="Cancel">x</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="dijitDialogPaneContent" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
    <div id="machineParameterDialogContents" class="machineParameterDialogContents">
      <span class="l-status-message-wrapper l-status-message-wrapper--dialog">
        <span id="machineParameterDialogStatus" class="c-global-message c-global-message--error">
          error: <span>Action not successful. Please correct the validation errors</span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <form id="machineParameterDialogForm" name="machineParameterDialogForm" action="/machineParameterAction.action" method="POST" class="c-panel-dialog">

      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="more-content">
    “Such a little helpless creature will only be in the way,” I said; “you had better pass him up to the Indian boys on the wharf, to be taken home to play with the children. This trip is not likely to be good for toy-dogs. The poor silly thing will be in rain and snow for weeks or months, and will require care like a baby.” But his master assured me that he would be no trouble at all; that he was a perfect wonder of a dog, could endure cold and hunger like a bear, swim like a seal, and was wondrous wise and cunning, etc., making out a list of virtues to show he might be the most interesting member of the party.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```